# How many words can TextView contain

Tags: android, textview

Now I have a TextView whose size is match parent, and I know its textsize, how can I get the max words it can contain without scrolling.

Comment: That is a really weird question to ask, considering words are typically not equal in size/length/width

Comment: Ok, What I mean is how many characters

Comment: @0X0nosugar understandable, but there's really no way to tell if it is a translation problem, and if it was - what the original intent was